# how to build lstm with functinal api?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am having a time series prediction problem and the data set has 4 variables.

My data set is like below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.columns=['var1','var2','var3','var4']
```

The timestamp is the index of my original data frame and I only take the values in the sorted order.

From this `var1` is my target variable to predict.I also need to key in 3-time lags so I prepare the dataset by below function:

```
# convert series to supervised learning
def series_to_supervised(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
    n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    cols, names = list(), list()
    # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1)
    for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
        cols.append(df.shift(i))
        names += [('var%d(t-%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # forecast sequence (t, t+1, ... t+n)
    for i in range(0, n_out):
        cols.append(df.shift(-i))
        if i == 0:
            names += [('var%d(t)' % (j+1)) for j in range(n_vars)]
        else:
            names += [('var%d(t+%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # put it all together
    agg = pd.concat(cols, axis=1)
    agg.columns = names
    # drop rows with NaN values
    if dropnan:
        agg.dropna(inplace=True)
    return agg

#take the 3 lags for each row
reframed = series_to_supervised(df,3, 1)
train_X=reframed.drop(['var1(t)'],axis=1)
train_y=reframed[['var1(t)']]

# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
```

So here the shape will be `(97, 16)` where 97 is the row count since the first three timesteps will not have 3 lags and the 16 is the overall columns with 3 lags plus the current time stamp.

Now in my case the value of `var1(t)` is also influenced by the `var2(t)`, `var3(t)`,`var4(t)`.
So my training shape of the data will be

```
   train_X shape  (97, 15)
   train_y shape  (97, 1)
```

Now the problem is how to reshape this into `[samples, timesteps, features]`.Because I can only do this if I drop `var2(t)`, `var3(t)`, `var4(t)` then I can reshape as [97,3,4] but in my case, I also want to include the current timestamp's remaining variable.

So then I found out that I can use the keras functional API to overcome this .

I created the model with keras functional API but something is wrong in the shape of the tensors.

```
def createFunctionalKerasLSTM():
    visible = Input(shape=(train_X.shape[0],train_X.shape[1]))
    hidden1 = LSTM(20)(visible)
    hidden2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(hidden1)
    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden2)
    model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
    return model
```

Error

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_14 is incompatible with the layer:
> expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 15]

I am not sure how to reshape in this case .because for normal LSTM I can drop the `var2(t)`, `var3(t)`, `var4(t)` and then reshape it (97,12) into (97,3,4) But here y shape is (97,15) so a bit confused how to reshape it properly to the input of the network.

Any help is appreciated!